# Electric potential due to two infinite planes as a function of $x$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, coulombs-law

**Problem**: Two infinite planes with surface charges $+\sigma$ and $-\sigma$ are perpendicular to the $x$-axis at $x=0$ and $x=2$ respectively. Determine an expression for the potential as a function of $x$ using:
$$V(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\int\frac{\sigma(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}da'$$
Calculate the electric field to check your answer.

**Attempt**:
I first calculate the potential for $x=0$. I attempt to use a cylinder where $s=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=\infty$, $x=x$ and $\phi=2\pi$:
$$V_1=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\int_0^s\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}d\phi ds=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-x)$$
For $x=2$:
$$V_2=-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2}-(x-2))$$
So that the potential is
$$V=V_1+V_2$$
When calculating the electric field, I get:
$$E_1=-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}-1)$$
$$E_2=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{s^2+(x-2^2)}}-1)$$
And by superposition
$$E=-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}-\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2}})$$
When I look at $E$, I don't get an answer that makes sense to me, but by looking at $E_1$ and $E_2$ separately, and knowing that they're gonna have different sign notations due to their different normal vectors, I feel like it could make sense.Would it correct to say that this is the answer:
$$V=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2})$$
$$
E=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x<0$ or $x>2$;}\\
\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_o} & \text{if $0<x<2$;}\\
\end{cases}
$$
I feel as if though calculating the electric field with Gauss' law and calculating the electric potential with a line integral makes this question much simpler, but the question says to do it this way so I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$You missed the jacobian of the polar coordinates: it should be
\begin{equation*}
V(x)=\frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^s\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}\dd\phi\,\dd s=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\lvert x\rvert).
\end{equation*}
The integral is anyway *almost* correct: when simplifying the square root you have $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$ and not just $x$.
This leads to the electric field (whose $y$ and $z$ components are necessarily zero because of the rotational symmetry around the $x$ axis)
\begin{equation*}
E(x)=-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\frac{\dd}{\dd x}\bigl[\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\lvert x\rvert\bigr]=
-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\biggl(\frac{x}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}-\operatorname{sign}(x)\bigg)
\end{equation*}
whic for $s\to+\infty$ is just $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\operatorname{sign}(x)$.
You can then superpose the electric field of the other plane, which, by analogy, is $-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\operatorname{sign}(x-2)$.

You are close, but your derivation is incorrect because you missed the absolute values of $x$ and $x-2$ in the electric fields: it's this peculiarity that gives the correct direction of the fields and makes them such that they cancel outside the region between the planes, and add inside it.

Comment: So by using the absolute signs and turning them into cases, would the potential as a function of x be: $$V=\begin{cases}\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2}+2) & \text{if } x<0\\\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2}-2x+2) & \text{if } 0<x<2\\\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_o}(\sqrt{s^2+x^2}-\sqrt{s^2+(x-2)^2}-2) & \text{if } x>2\\\end{cases}$$ Ideally, this gives me electric potentials all at infinity it seems like, which is a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, the potential function is correct. I don't understand the last sentence...

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is, that since it's an infinite plane, by plugging that into the equation I put, the electric potential would be at infinity for all positions. But thank you for your feedback! I wanted to understand the concepts because an extension of the question would be to draw a graph to represent this and I thought it wouldn't make sense if I drew a graph where the potential was at infinity everywhere.

Comment: Yes, for $s\to+\infty$ you have a potential that is infinite everywhere. The problem lies in the fact that the integral formula to calculate the potential you used implies that the reference point for the potential is infinity, where there is no charge. But that doesn't happen in this idealised case, since the plane itself extends to infinity.
In fact, if you start from the electric field and integrate to get the potential, you arrive to the same solution if you integrate from $x=\infty$ to a given distance $x$ from the plane.

Comment: You can get around this by setting the reference point somewhere in the plane: you obtain a linear function of $x$.